Cuda atomic (CAS, Exch) loop hangs
I'm trying to implement Cuda blocking, loosely following this tutorial
I have tried to implement that code but the loop hangs.
Similarly, I have implemented this in a kernel, where mutex is allocated on device:
int state = 0;
int * mutex;
CudaMalloc(&mutex, sizeof(int) );
cudaMemcpy(mutex, &state , sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    
mykernel<<< 1, 9>>>(mutex);

__global__ void mykernel(int * mutex){
int ti = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;

printf("TESTATOM0 -- THREAD%d MUTEX:%d\n", ti, *mutex);
printf("TESTATOM1 -- THREAD%d MUTEX:%d  RETURN:%d\n", ti, *mutex, atomicCAS(mutex, 0, 1));
printf("TESTATOM2 -- THREAD%d MUTEX:%d\n", ti, *mutex);

atomicExch(mutex, 0);

printf("TESTATOM3 -- THREAD%d MUTEX:%d\n", ti, *mutex);
}


The output:
TESTATOM0 -- THREAD0 MUTEX:0
TESTATOM0 -- THREAD1 MUTEX:0
TESTATOM0 -- THREAD2 MUTEX:0
TESTATOM0 -- THREAD3 MUTEX:0
TESTATOM0 -- THREAD4 MUTEX:0
TESTATOM0 -- THREAD5 MUTEX:0
TESTATOM0 -- THREAD6 MUTEX:0
TESTATOM0 -- THREAD7 MUTEX:0
TESTATOM0 -- THREAD8 MUTEX:0
TESTATOM1 -- THREAD0 MUTEX:0  RETURN:0
TESTATOM1 -- THREAD1 MUTEX:0  RETURN:1
TESTATOM1 -- THREAD2 MUTEX:0  RETURN:1
TESTATOM1 -- THREAD3 MUTEX:0  RETURN:1
TESTATOM1 -- THREAD4 MUTEX:0  RETURN:1
TESTATOM1 -- THREAD5 MUTEX:0  RETURN:1
TESTATOM1 -- THREAD6 MUTEX:0  RETURN:1
TESTATOM1 -- THREAD7 MUTEX:0  RETURN:1
TESTATOM1 -- THREAD8 MUTEX:0  RETURN:1
TESTATOM2 -- THREAD0 MUTEX:1
TESTATOM2 -- THREAD1 MUTEX:1
TESTATOM2 -- THREAD2 MUTEX:1
TESTATOM2 -- THREAD3 MUTEX:1
TESTATOM2 -- THREAD4 MUTEX:1
TESTATOM2 -- THREAD5 MUTEX:1
TESTATOM2 -- THREAD6 MUTEX:1
TESTATOM2 -- THREAD7 MUTEX:1
TESTATOM2 -- THREAD8 MUTEX:1
TESTATOM3 -- THREAD0 MUTEX:0
TESTATOM3 -- THREAD1 MUTEX:0
TESTATOM3 -- THREAD2 MUTEX:0
TESTATOM3 -- THREAD3 MUTEX:0
TESTATOM3 -- THREAD4 MUTEX:0
TESTATOM3 -- THREAD5 MUTEX:0
TESTATOM3 -- THREAD6 MUTEX:0
TESTATOM3 -- THREAD7 MUTEX:0
TESTATOM3 -- THREAD8 MUTEX:0

Notice the first thread returns 0 and the rest return 1
But when I try and implement this in a while blocking loop
    printf("TESTATOM0 -- THREAD%d MUTEX:%d\n", ti, *mutex);
    while (atomicCAS(mutex, 0, 1) == 1);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("BLOCKED -- THREAD%d MUTEX:%d\n", ti, *mutex);
    }
    
    atomicExch(mutex, 0);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("UNBLOCKED -- THREAD%d MUTEX:%d\n", ti, *mutex);
    }

The ouput is:
TESTATOM0 -- THREAD0 MUTEX:0
TESTATOM0 -- THREAD1 MUTEX:0
TESTATOM0 -- THREAD2 MUTEX:0
TESTATOM0 -- THREAD3 MUTEX:0
TESTATOM0 -- THREAD4 MUTEX:0
TESTATOM0 -- THREAD5 MUTEX:0
TESTATOM0 -- THREAD6 MUTEX:0
TESTATOM0 -- THREAD7 MUTEX:0
TESTATOM0 -- THREAD8 MUTEX:0

The program then hangs and I have to exit from the command line.
Compiled and run as:
nvcc -o ppmer -ccbin "D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" ppmwriter.cu > .\outputs\AA_CURRENT_ERROR.txt

ppmer > .\outputs\AA_CURRENT_OUTPUT.txt 

I'm using Nvidia GeForce GTX 1650 with Max-Q design
I assume the loop is not terminating but I have no clue why?

Try to compile for your Turing architecture GPU with -arch=sm_75.

@paleonix working now, thanks. I was sure I did everything right in the code lol. So what was the problem then?

You can find many old questions on this topic, see e.g. Cuda Mutex, why deadlock?. This general issue was resolved with Independent Thread Scheduling since Volta. But even when your GPU supports it, if you don't tell the compiler to compile for at least Volta (sm_70), you will still get the old behavior.

So basically if you only consider running your code on recent GPUs, it is fine. If you want to code for Pascal and earlier GPUs, your code is flawed.

@paleonix I'm just using it for debugging because it's brutal trying to trace one thread through pages and pages of weaved print ouput -- so no issues there. If you want to put that in an answer I'll accept.

a more modern approach compared to the roll-your-own atomic lock is here.

As per the comments from paleonix, the solution is the compile option:
-arch=sm_75

